Clang compiler cannot find the definition of template introduced by using-declaration. gcc and msvc see no problem
I've hit a scenario where gcc and clang have different opinions on the same piece of code. To my best understanding of using-declarations and inline namespaces, clang is wrong.
Example below works as intended with gcc 14.2 and msvc v19.40, but clang 19 produces unexpected error at line marked (2). So I'd like to ask language lawyers: is the example below well-formed and should it be accepted by clang too.
The code (godbolt link):
// Goal of this study:
//    - allow access to `Data` via public namespace lib::api.
//    - forbid access to `Data` via private namespace lib::impl_v1.

namespace lib::impl_v1 {
template <typename T>
struct Data;
} // namespace lib::impl_v1

namespace lib::api {
using impl_v1::Data;
} // namespace lib::api

namespace lib::impl_v1 {
inline namespace please_access_this_symbol_through_lib_api_namespace {
template <typename T> struct Data;                 // (1)
} // inline namespace please_access_this_symbol_through_lib_api_namespace
} // namespace lib::impl_v1

namespace lib::impl_v1 {
template <typename T>
struct Data
{
};
} // namespace lib::impl_v1

int main()
{
    lib::api::Data<int>       x;      // (2) clang error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'lib::impl_v1::Data<int>'
//    lib::impl_v1::Data<int>   y;    // (3) The goal is to get error at this line: reference to 'Data' is ambiguous
    return 0;
}

Playing with this code, I've found that clang error at line (2) is gone if I comment out the line marked (1). But that ruins the whole point of this trick, so obviously I'd like to keep line (1) in.
The error at line (3) is intentional.

The code is very hard for reading when 1 one of a real code is surrounded with 2 grey lines of comments above and below. A [mre] can be https://godbolt.org/z/jf3T1a35W

@3CxEZiVlQ I hope it's better now.

@3CxEZiVlQ, that minimal example you suggest lacks the definition of lib::impl_v1::Data template. No wonder it gives an error. But in my example the definition is actually present.
